# How to delete event without notifying host (I don't want to change "Yes" to "No")

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, notifications, delete

After receiving a gmail invitation for an event that I plan to attend, I like to duplicate the event and then change the times to include my travel to and from the event, add a destination address, add my own notes, etc. ... and then delete the automatically created event, leaving only my own version.  HOWEVER, when I do that, this changes my "will you attend" response from Yes to No, which can confuse the organizer and other attendees.  Is there a way around this?

Note: I know I can edit the automatically created event (with those changes showing only on my calendar) but my understanding is that my edits disappear whenever the organizer makes a change to the event.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Calendar there is no way to have a Google Account as an attendee while also not having the event attached to that Google account's calendar.

##### Updates

You point out that event updates made by the owner ***will take priority*** over an attendee's  updates.

What isn't noted in your question is that duplicating then deleting the event leaves you with the opposite problem.  Event updates made by the owner ***will not*** update your duplicated event.

If concern for updates factors in to your calculus, concern for the loss of owner updates should take precedence.  At the end of the day one should always have the event owner's current version.

##### Visual Noise

There are solutions for Chrome Desktop that **visually** merge duplicate events.  For example, this Chrome extension [Extensions > Event Merge for Google Calendar™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/event-merge-for-google-ca/idehaflielbgpaokehlhidbjlehlfcep?hl=en) also on Github at [imightbeamy/gcal-multical-event-merge](https://github.com/imightbeamy/gcal-multical-event-merge).

> *[Extensions > Event Merge for Google Calendar™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/event-merge-for-google-ca/idehaflielbgpaokehlhidbjlehlfcep?hl=en)*
> *When using Google Calendar™ you may have one event on multiple calendars. For instance on your work and personal calendar, on your work calendar and your team's shared calendar, or on many co-work's calendars. These can clutter up your calendar and make it hard to read. This extension merges all those separate events into one event, and gives it stripes with all the individual calendars' colors.*

I have used the extension for several years and it works very well and can be toggled on and off.  Changing the title or address might cause it to see the events as different, but you can edit the descriptions.

The code is available on GitHub and the [GNU GPL license](https://github.com/imightbeamy/gcal-multical-event-merge/blob/master/LICENSE) allows modification.  One could tweak the extension's code to ignore addresses, and other things.

##### Main Fork is Out of Date

The main fork hasn't been updated in many (many) years but that hasn't been a problem for me.  Others who have run into various [issues with the old version](https://github.com/imightbeamy/gcal-multical-event-merge/issues/87#issuecomment-1219797437) have been directed to [HCAWN's](https://github.com/HCAWN) fork that was updated a few months ago on Github [HCAWN/gcal-multical-event-merge](https://github.com/HCAWN/gcal-multical-event-merge) as well as Google [Extensions > Cal Merge for Google Calendar™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cal-merge-for-google-cale/dchpdbljalbfnelbfbgncfidhjoibkah)

[image: Event Merge for Google Calendar™]

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. These are family events and, at least for my personal situation, I am not concerned about changes made on the host's calendar, although I do understand the theoretical risk of a host making a change and not sending an email reflecting their update (i.e., the risk of them performing a 'silent' update).

Comment: It seems like one should be able to control what appears on one's own calendar without also confusing the host.  Most definitely a first world problem but perhaps someday a solution will reveal itself.  Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Another, less than ideal option is to copy those events onto a secondary calendar, and then hide one or the other.

Comment: If I answered your question (I know it wasn't what you wanted to hear ;-) Consider accepting and/or upvoting it.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Blind Spots Thank you for your reply but I don't see how to "hide" an event in my Google Calendar.  I tried googling "hide in Google Calendar" but did not find anything that looked relevant.   Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I may have not been clear, while you cannot natively hide/unhide events, you can hide/unhide calendars.  If you use a secondary calendar for your copied events, instead of copying them to your primary you could choose what calendars to display.    I also use an extension [Calendar Selector for Google Calendar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/calendar-selector-for-goo/nmliklikilkjommabacojbijjimlgjck) that allows me to quickly toggle between pre-defined combinations of calendar and save default views etc.